# Ubuntu Update Manager fails to download packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, updates

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10.

When there are packages update available, the Update Manager fails to download them, with the error message `"[ftp://remote/file/blah.deb] not found"`.

But, if I open a terminal window (Konsole), and execute `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, the exact same package list gets downloaded and update successfully.

Any clues about what could cause the Update Manager to fail (every time), but apt-get would succeed?

I didn't had this problem before upgrading (from Ubuntu 9.04).

Comment: may your issue be related with [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1348686&page=2)?

Comment: I don't think so, since the Update Manager is showing me the packages to update.  The problem is that it fails to download them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found the problem.

The Update Manager (which is, in fact, KPackageKit) will use proxy configured in `.kde/share/config/kioslaverc`.  But, under KUbuntu 9.10, this proxy setting are not displayed in the settings...  They are not displayed in Konqueror, or in Network Settings...  So there was no way to find that problem.

Thanks to this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1321869) for information about those proxy settings.